# List web directory with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to list all the files contained in the directory found here: ftp://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/ with PHP.  It would be nice if the file listing could be returned as an array.  It doesn't have to be the FTP protocol, but I read somewhere that HTTP will not work in this application.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ftp_nlist()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) function.

```
$array = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "/downloads/releases/");
```

Alternatively, you can parse the HTTP directory listing [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2270921/625231).

Comment: I'm confused as to parsing the HTTP directory, which seems like the best option. Could you explain that a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: It's explained very well in the post I linked to, you should be able to write the code yourself using the steps mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Use ftp_nlist which will return an array of all files. Here is an example I found for FTP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_nlist.asp

```
<?php
 $conn = ftp_connect("ftp.testftp.com") or die("Could not connect");
 ftp_login($conn,"admin","ert456");

 print_r(ftp_nlist($conn,"images"));

 ftp_close($conn);
 ?>
```

In above example "images" is your return array.

Listing directories for HTTP (web server) is controlled through Web Server Settings and most of the webserver have it already set. If any http web server  is set not to display directory listing, you can not list directories on any Web Server.